# How to disable a button when an input field is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I tried this but it’s not working.

```js
$('#booking').attr('disabled', true);
$('input:text').keyup(function() {
  var disable = false;
  
  $('input:text').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      disable = true;
    }
  });
  $('#booking').prop('disabled', disable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('home/program/booking');?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tour </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="tour" name="tour" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="firstname" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="booking" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: May I ask if you included the jQuery library? ... As I know see that your code does work already if you just do that

Answer (score 1):

You should use `disable='disabled'` and `disabled=''` instead of `true`/`false`, though using jQuery it will work with both

And with jQuery you should use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

```js
$('#booking').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var d = '';
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      d = 'disabled';
    }
  });
  $('#booking').prop('disabled', d);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('home/program/booking');?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tour</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="tour" name="tour" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="firstname" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="booking" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">OK</button>
</form>
```

*Update*

Did you add the jQuery library to your solution? ... If I do that on your existing code it actually does work as is, as you can see in below sample

```js
$('#booking').prop('disabled', true);
$('input:text').keyup(function() {
  var disable = false;
  $('input:text').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      disable = true;
    }
  });
  $('#booking').prop('disabled', disable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('home/program/booking');?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tour</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="tour" name="tour" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="firstname" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="booking" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">OK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` in your function once when it hits a input box with an empty value instead of keep looking through and changing the that `disable` variable

```js
$('#booking').attr('disabled', true);
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var disable = false;
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $('#booking').attr('disabled', true);
      return
    } else {
      $('#booking').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('home/program/booking');?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tour</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="tour" name="tour" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="firstname" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="booking" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">OK</button>
```